# Upload Image on server using php but it doesn't exsist on server

Tags: php, image, file, upload

I am really confused I have this image upload code and it's working fine on my home server "Xampp" and when I click on upload button it upload image and send it to Upload folder but When I upload this php and html page to server and works fine but it can't save image to Upload folder on server please help me out. Thanks

you can try it on my site

http://bing.freevar.com/image_upload.html

Here is HTML file

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is a PHP file

```
<?php


$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] <= 200000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 10024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
  chmod("upload", 0644);
?>
```

Comment: *"you can try it on my site"* - Um... no. Post your code.

Comment: Check for file/folder permissions settings and also your max upload size etc. too many things can go wrong, and many of them all at the same time.

Comment: `chmod("upload", 0644);` try removing that or use either `chmod("upload", 0777);` or `chmod("upload", 0755);`

Comment: Tried both of these codes but still not working @Fred-ii-

Comment: The chmod only happens at the end of execution. Try chmod'ing via FTP and remove that part from your code. Also make sure that the sub-folder exists to start with.

Comment: Can you give me working php code? @Fred-ii-

Comment: I got this error when I tried chmoding via ftp
Stored in: upload/f.jpgcould not chmod upload_file.php

Answer (score 0):

If it works on your local server, but not on production you need to make sure that the folder exists on the production server and that it can be written to by the user account that the PHP script is executing under.

Comment: As test, chmod it to 777 and see if you can upload to it. (Don't leave it at 777, that's dangerous; just while you're testing)

Answer (score 0):

I think you got this PHP script from this link of [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp). This php script has two extra parentheses in if condition. Remove these extra parentheses.

```
if (/*removed*/($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
       || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
       || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
       || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
       || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
       || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")// removed
       && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
       && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
```

It worked for me. Hope it will work for you also. I think you need more validation. You can use **getimagesize()** function to check width, height, MIME type, attr of the uploaded image.

Comment: still not working :( actually code is correct but when i click on upload it gives me following data 
`Upload: 23.jpg
Type: image/jpeg
Size: 6.4533120510774 kB
Temp file: /tmp/phpv3iNxw
Stored in: upload/23.jpg `

but when i check the file in upload folder it doesn't exist

Comment: Check your folder name correctly. Now remove all validation first only to check that the image is being uploaded or not. Just use move_uploaded_file (/**if you wrote it correctly it's not move_upload_file*/) to move the image from the temporary folder to the permanent folder.